# Dynamic Loading Image View

Tags: android, imageview

Hi I am trying to dynamically load an ImageView in a ListView this code doesnt seem to work.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
    String uri = "@drawable/"+myImage[position];
    int imageResource = mycontext.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,   mycontext.getPackageName());
    ImageView imageview= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPic);
    Drawable res = mycontext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageview.setImageDrawable(res);
}
```

Log

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1195)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:729)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:711)
        at parser.my.myapplication.NotificationAdapter.getView(NotificationAdapter.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add `"@drawable/"` before drawable name.Get drawable id using `getIdentifier` :

```
String uri = myImage[position];
int imageResource = mycontext.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, 
                                      "drawable",   mycontext.getPackageName());
 imageview.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Comment: its giving android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 on line :  Drawable res = mycontext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

Comment: @RonDavis: see my annswer

Comment: thnx it worked.. i was passing file extension in myImage[position].